# pdftk dump_data_fields does not include checkbox labels

Tags: php, pdf, checkbox, pdftk

I am using `pdftk` to dump the datafields from my editable PDF. I want to get checkbox field names, or you can say labels for the checkboxes. The problem is that the file generated by `dump_data_fields` doesn't return the exact checkbox labels; instead it shows the checkbox description.

For example:

```
FieldType: Button
FieldName: ResidentialStructure_Basement_FoundationFinishedIndicator_A
FieldNameAlt: Check the box (if applicable): Indicates the basement/recreation room is finished. 
FieldFlags: 8388608
FieldJustification: Left
FieldStateOption: 1
FieldStateOption: Off
---
FieldType: Button
FieldName: ResidentialStructure_Basement_FoundationWalkOutIndicator_A
FieldNameAlt: Check the box (if applicable): Indicates the basement/recreation room is a walk out. 
FieldFlags: 8388608
FieldJustification: Left
FieldStateOption: 1
FieldStateOption: Off
```

The real labels of these 2 checkboxes in the PDF document are `finished` and `walk out`, but we only get descriptions of these checkboxes as shown above in `FieldName` and `FieldNameAlt`.

Is there any way to get exact checkbox labels using `dump_data_fields` or any other property of `pdftk`?

Comment: What you call *checkbox labels* most likely merely is text positioned near the checkbox. Most likely there is no actual connection between label and checkbox inside the pdf. (As you have not shared the pdf in question, I cannot tell for sure. )

Comment: Here pdf's are the accord forms from which i need checkbox label or as u said text positioned near checkbox.Currently i am getting checkbox description from pdftk by dumping data in text file but not the exact text.

Comment: is this possible or not ?

Comment: @Ks21: I want xfa data from form pdf. How do i will achieve. Please help.